# Copying Mozilla Profile Files from Windows XP To Windows Seven

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, firefox

I have been using XP from last 2-3 years and now going to install Windows seven in my system. I want to keep all the 3 profiles i have created along with history, passwords, book marks etc.

I know that Mozilla keeps all the info at specific path

```
%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\
```

In Windows XP ,i keep backup and copy paste all the files in new profiles then it works. but I am afraid  that those file might not work in Windows Seven.

Has anybody tried ?
Any Suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [MozBackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) when backing up or transferring Mozilla account data. It collects and compresses all the files of the selected profile. Transfer MozBackup and the archive file to the new computer and use the restore function.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use [FEBE](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/febe/) extension - it's very handy, it has a lot of options, you can selectively choose what you want to back up and even schedule automatic back-ups.

Answer (score 0):

I installed firefox in newly installed windows 7 & i created 2 profiles in that. Then i copied the all the old files to new profiles. I did it manually without using Mozbackup.

And it worked. My all history,Bookmarks, Passwords are working.

I have  tried [Mozbackup](http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/) on another system & it worked.